# Efficient way to toggle between numbers in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm making a Tic-Tac-Toe application for Android, and I'm looking to toggle between 2 players (0 - 1) when taking turns. 0 will be for the first player; 1 for the second.

The easiest way to achieve this is by doing:

```
if (currentPlayer == 1) {
   currentPlayer = 0
} else {
   currentPlayer = 1
}
```

But are there any more efficient ways to go about it with Kotlin? Thanks in advance

Comment: The duplicate shows an XOR approach, which looks like `currentPlayer = currentPlayer xor 1` in Kotlin. Not particularly shorter than the subtraction approach, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Kotlin specific, it's just simple:

```
currentPlayer = 1 - currentPlayer
```